# Issue with match() and email regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I have a function where I get the HTML of a website, then use `String.prototype.match` along with a regex rule to get the emails in that page. However, for some reason, I'm getting back a line that matches the regex without the actual email plus all of the DOM appended.

So my problems are:

1. My regex is not actually working. I don't get the email part of `mailto:xxxx`.
2. For some reason, the whole DOM is getting console logged when I do `console.log(matches[0]);`

```js
const websiteEmailRegex = 'mailto:([^\?]*)';

let HTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML;

let matches = HTML.match(websiteEmailRegex);
if(matches)
{
    console.log('email', matches[0]);
}
```

This is what I get in console:

```html
mailto:info@tartaytantas.es"> info@tartaytantas.es</a></p>
<p>No cogemos pedidos por mail.</p>


<p></p>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                <footer class="entry-footer">
                                        </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
        </div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->

                </main><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

</div></div>
        <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">

                <div class="container">

                            <div class="footer-t">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="three-cols">
                <div class="col">
                                    </div>
                <div class="col center">
                    <section class="widget widget_contact_form">
                                        </section>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-info">
        <span>
        ©2020 <a href="http://tartaytantas.es/">Tartaytantas - Tartas y bizccochos a domicilio en Aravaca</a>.        </span>
        Bakes and Cakes | Desarrollado por        <a href="https://rarathemes.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
            Rara Theme        </a>
        Funciona gracias a <a href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress.</a>

    </div><!-- .site-info -->

                </div>

        </footer><!-- #colophon -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-top"><span>Arriba</span></a>

        </div><!-- #acc-content -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secureservercdn.net/160.153.137.170/zm5.b57.myftpupload.com/wp-content/themes/bakes-and-cakes/js/owl.carousel.min.js
```

Comment: You should check the contents of `match`, the index `0` contains the whole match, index `1` and following the capturing groups.

Comment: matches[1] returns the same thing

Comment: Are you sure it returns the same thing and not just the part after the `mailto:`. That it returns more then expected is because `([^\?]*)` will match everything that is not `\?`.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `mailto:([^\?]*)` matches `mailto:` and then everything that isn't `?`.

Assuming you're just trying to capture all `mailto` URLs (in `<a>` tags), you could update your regex to capture everything but the closing quote (`"` or `'`) of the HTML attribute:

```js
const websiteEmailRegex = 'mailto:([^\"\']+)';
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7dPpAi/1)

Comment: This works good thanks! Is there a way to not capute the mailto: part, only the email itself